# How get only token using sed, grep or awk?

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, jwt

The Token is on middle of lines.
I tried some possibilities, but not match, like:

```
sed -n '/matched/,$p' file
sed -n '/token=/,$p' file > out.txt
grep -oP '(?<=token: ).*' file
grep -Po 'token\s\K.*' file
```

I have this:

```
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/procedimento?filter%5B%5D=status,eq,SIM&filter%5B%5D=clinicaId,eq,50&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 71194 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/salas?filter=clinicaId,eq,50&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 303 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "PUT /api_producao.php/sala_horario/14 HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/sala_horario?filter=salaID,eq,15&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 141 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:33 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/aux_clinica_profissional?filter=clinicaId,eq,42&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4 HTTP/1.1" 200 2730 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:33 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/profissional?filter=id,in,5,0,9,7,51,10,25,24,33,34,48,0,45,27,105,130,115,118,119,124,0,127&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4 HTTP/1.1" 200 10827 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:33 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/sala_horario?filter=salaID,eq,15&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 141 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
```

And need this:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```sh
grep -Po 'token=\K\S+' file
```

Sed solution:

```sh
sed -nE 's/.*token=([^[:space:]]+).*/\1/p' file
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oinrzq/1). *Details*:

- `token=` - a fixed substring
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the current match memory buffer
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/bYJMOd):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/procedimento?filter%5B%5D=status,eq,SIM&filter%5B%5D=clinicaId,eq,50&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 71194 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/salas?filter=clinicaId,eq,50&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 303 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "PUT /api_producao.php/sala_horario/14 HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/sala_horario?filter=salaID,eq,15&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 141 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:33 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/aux_clinica_profissional?filter=clinicaId,eq,42&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4 HTTP/1.1" 200 2730 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:33 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/profissional?filter=id,in,5,0,9,7,51,10,25,24,33,34,48,0,45,27,105,130,115,118,119,124,0,127&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4 HTTP/1.1" 200 10827 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:33 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/sala_horario?filter=salaID,eq,15&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 141 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"'
grep -Po 'token=\K\S+' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
```

The sed command means

- `-n` - suppress default line output
- `E` - enable POSIX ERE syntax
- `.*token=([^[:space:]]+).*` - find any text, then `token=`, then capture any one or more non-whitespace chars into Group 1 and then match the rest of the text on the line
- `\1` - replace the match with Group 1  value
- `p` - `p`rint the result of the substitution.

**NOTE**:

Whenever the value you need to extract has no space + protocol name right after it, and there can be other query params after the `token` one, you need to negate `&` as well as whitespace. Then just use `grep -Po 'token=\K[^&\s]+' file` and `sed -nE 's/.*token=([^&[:space:]]+).*/\1/p' file`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want

```
sed -n 's/.*token=\([^ &]*\).*/\1/p' file
```

or

```
grep -Po 'token=\K[^ &]*' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/GET/{s/.*=//;s/ .*//p}' input_file
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting:

```
 grep -oP '(?<=&token)[^ ]*' input.1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more verbose but also more portable version - It's basically doing the good ole' `$1=$1`

1. after using `FS` itself to locate where the token is,
2. use 1 call to `sub()` to clean the tail end of
   anything that isn't part of the JSON token
3. force a comparison of "`less than empty string`",
   which is always false (0), and anything raised
   to zero-th power in `awk` becomes a numeric one (1),

thus allowing the entirety of the stuff inside

```
`$( )`
```

to become `$(1)`, and using one more time of `$1=$1` to auto-trim blanks at both ends

```
[m/n/g]awk '

 BEGIN { _=(___=index(FS="^.+[&]"\
            "token=","."))~(__="")
 } +_<NF &&  \
              \
($_=$(($!_=$___)^(sub("([& ].*)?$",__)<__)))' <<< "${s}"
```

- `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE`
- `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4`
  .
  .
  .

Tested and confirmed to work on gawk 5.1.1, mawk 1.3.4, mawk 1.9.9.6, and macOS nawk

— The 4Chan Teller

Answer (score 1):

With awk you can use the [match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function, and take the 6 characters of `token=` into account when printing.

The `[^[:space:]]+` part in the pattern matches 1 or more occurrences of any character except whitespace characters

```
awk 'match($0, /token=[^[:space:]]+/) {
  print substr($0, RSTART+6, RLENGTH-6)
}' file
```

Output

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed `jwt` tag in your question, [`JWT`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) uses base64 encoding, it starts with header which must have 2 keys: `alg` and `typ`, order is not important so prefix might be either `{"alg"` or `{"typ"` which after base64-encodings gives `eyJhbGci` or `eyJ0eXAi`. Taking above considerations in account I would use GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/procedimento?filter%5B%5D=status,eq,SIM&filter%5B%5D=clinicaId,eq,50&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 71194 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/salas?filter=clinicaId,eq,50&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 303 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "PUT /api_producao.php/sala_horario/14 HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:32 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/sala_horario?filter=salaID,eq,15&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 141 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:33 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/aux_clinica_profissional?filter=clinicaId,eq,42&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4 HTTP/1.1" 200 2730 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:33 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/profissional?filter=id,in,5,0,9,7,51,10,25,24,33,34,48,0,45,27,105,130,115,118,119,124,0,127&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2RycG9ydG8uY29tLmJyL2JhY2svb2RvbnRvbG9naWEvcHVibGljL2FwaS92MS9zaWduaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NDg0ODc1OTksImV4cCI6MTY0ODQ5MTE5OSwibmJmIjoxNjQ4NDg3NTk5LCJqdGkiOiJUZEtqTnlnWWxiZkJmVEpWIn0.ZNIZJtJQS8BbITnkgGL8j-8g7q47nZ7TTdIA2-6s2k4 HTTP/1.1" 200 10827 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
207.244.229.206 - - [28/Mar/2022:14:35:33 -0300] "GET /api_producao.php/sala_horario?filter=salaID,eq,15&transform=1&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjExMSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zZHJwb3J0by5jb20uYnIvYmFjay9vZG9udG9sb2dpYS9wdWJsaWMvYXBpL3YxL3NpZ25pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY0ODQ4Njk4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjQ4NDkwNTgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NDg0ODY5ODAsImp0aSI6IndsZVNhZ1ppb3VWVUFRb2cifQ.gnAzxxtWNdUY_Ech0Lj5v8TNMvSTOnjLWLHYhY3eMvE HTTP/1.1" 200 141 "-" "GuzzleHttp/6.5.5 curl/7.81.0 PHP/7.4.28"
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="(eyJhbGci|eyJ0eXAi)[-_=A-Za-z0-9]+"}NF{print $1}' file.txt
```

output

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
```

Explanation: I use `FPAT` (Field Pattern) to inform GNU `AWK` that field starts with `eyJhbGci` or `eyJ0eXAi` which is then followed by 1 or more of characters from **Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet**
as described in [RFC3548](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3548.html) (ASCII letters, ASCII digits, minus, understrike, equal sign)

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*